# How to resolve this type conflict in FStar?

Tags: fstar

Here's a simple pattern generator that returns a list of `1:nat`. `lemma_1` proves that there's a 1 in every position of generated lists of arbitrary length. The `lng` argument for `nth_1` had to be introduced because otherwise `n` would be constrained as `n:nat{n < length lst}` causing a type conflict with the `n` in `lemma_1` whose type would be `n:nat{n < lng}`. How could this be solved without the extra parameter?

```
val length: list 'a -> nat
let rec length lst = 
match lst with
  | [] -> 0
  | _ :: t -> 1 + length t

val nth_1 : lst: list nat {length lst > 0} -> (lng: nat) -> n: nat {n < lng} -> nat
let rec nth_1 lst lng n =
  match lst with
  | [h] -> h
  | h :: t -> if n = 0 then h else nth_1 t (lng - 1) (n - 1)

val gen_1 : lng: nat {lng > 0} -> list nat
let rec gen_1 lng =
match lng with 
  | 1 -> [1]
  | _ -> 1 :: gen_1 (lng - 1)

let rec lemma_1 (lng: nat {lng > 0}) (n: nat {n < lng})  : Lemma ((nth_1 (gen_1 lng) lng n) = 1) =
match n with
  | 0 -> ()
  | _ -> lemma_1 (lng - 1) (n - 1)
```

It seems the problem is in connection with the constraint that `gen_1` patterns must not be zero length. Is there a better way to express this criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to avoid the extra parameter (please see the comments inline):

```
module Test

val length: list α → ℕ
let rec length lst =
match lst with
  | [] → 0
  | _ ⸬ t → 1 + length t

//the refinement on n is not really necessary here, the proofs work even without it
//because as soon as we have [h], irrespective of the value of n, we return h
val nth_1 : lst: list ℕ {length lst > 0} → n: ℕ{n < length lst} → ℕ
let rec nth_1 lst n =
  match lst with
  | [h] → h
  | h ⸬ t → if n = 0 then h else nth_1 t (n - 1)

//refine the return type to say that it returns a list of length lng
val gen_1 : lng: pos → (l:list ℕ{length l == lng})
let rec gen_1 lng =
match lng with
  | 1 → [1]
  | _ → 1 ⸬ gen_1 (lng - 1)

let rec lemma_1 (lng: pos) (n: ℕ {n < lng})  : Lemma ((nth_1 (gen_1 lng) n) = 1) =
match n with
  | 0 → ()
  | _ → lemma_1 (lng - 1) (n - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it correct to say that it's already proved that gen_1 lists satisfy the refinement (length l == lng)?

Comment: Indeed, that's how a typechecked function `f` with type `a -> b` should be interpreted ... when given an argument of type `a`, the function terminates and returns a value of type `b`.